# Classical References on Stability of Autonomous and Non-autonomous Systems and Lyapunov Stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

I ask for classical, but not much advanced books or articles in Stability of Autonomous and Non-autonomous Systems and Lyapunov Stability.

I mean: a book where the definitions and examples are in easy access, but the kind of book that we could reference/cite without fear..!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two standard textbooks:

1. Khalil, Hassan K., and Jessy W. Grizzle. Nonlinear systems. Vol. 3. Upper Saddle River, NJ: Prentice hall, 2002.
2. Slotine, Jean-Jacques E., and Weiping Li. Applied nonlinear control. Vol. 199. No. 1. Englewood Cliffs, NJ: Prentice hall, 1991.

Note that the first book is somewhat detailed, and a simplified "student" edition was recently published:

3. Khalil, Hassan K. Nonlinear control. Pearson Higher Ed, 2014.

Comment: Thank you so much!